# Laravel 5.5 - Валидация строки внутри объекта, который внутри массива

Tags: laravel5

есть request:

```
`array:2 [
  "alt_tags" => "1"
  "name_pattern" => array:2 [
    0 => "{"label":"Main Title","value":"main_title"}"
    1 => "{"label":"Store Name","value":"store_name"}"
  ]
]`
```

В классе Request, я пытался валидировать следующим способом, но безрезультатно:

```
`$labels = \implode(',', [
        'Main Title',
        'Store Name',
    ]);

 $values = \implode(',', [
        'main_title',
        'store_name',
    ]);

 return [
        'alt_tags'        => 'required|boolean',
        'name_pattern'         => 'required|array|min:0|max:2',
        'name_pattern.*.label' => "sometimes|string|in:{$labels}",
        'name_pattern.*.value' => "sometimes|string|in:{$values}",
        ];`
```

при проверке name_pattern.*.label возвращает NULL:

```
data_get(request()->all(), 'name_pattern.0') // "{"label":"Main Title","value":"main_title"}"
data_get(request()->all(),'name_pattern.0.label');  // return NULL
```

Просьба помочь с валидаций строк внутри объекта.

Comment: На [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/) или переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: спасибо, перевел